# Python Pandas: Concatenating dataframes misses columns

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I am reading multiple csv files from a folder and concatenates them inside a dataframe before loading them into SQL server database. But the problem that I am facing is that some of csv files have additional columns and have different order. The concatenation method simply ignores them and adds empty values in most of the columns. Is there any way to fix it? i.e. All the columns should have appropriate values and additional colums show have 'N/A' where it does not exist. I am using below code:

'''

```
db = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + "?" + Driver)
##################################################
parsed_families=os.listdir(Input_dir)
##################################################

def process_file():
    reqd_counters=cg_list()
    for name in parsed_families:
        if name in (reqd_counters):

            folder_path=os.path.join(Input_dir,name)
            file_name=os.listdir(folder_path)

            all_file_path=glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,"*.csv"))
            df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv,all_file_path ))
            df['dateTime'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('+04:00',''))
            outputdict = sqlcol(df)
            df.to_csv(os.path.join(Test_df_csv,name),sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
            df.to_sql(name, db,if_exists="append",  index=False, dtype=outputdict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_file()
```

'''
[Desired Input and Outputs are:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we9j2.png)

My code is also adding duplicate column names which needs to be consolidated as we have is done in Column B in desired output.

Comment: Could you please post a small example of the input and what is your desired output?

Comment: I have added the desired output in the snapshot

Comment: Concat should behave exactly as you show, so the column duplication might be happening somewhere else in the code. Are you sure they have the same name, maybe some are capitals and others in lower case?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Bulls Eye.. You were exactly right. CSV was fine but error comes out be NaN values in duplicate columns ...I had to pick the actual value and ignore the Nan value. These values were randomly coming in duplicate col1 or col2...thus causing this issue.. I had made the columns to upper to fix it  and then merge the columns.. Will update the code in a while for your review

Answer (score 0):

given your described input and output you just need to use `pd.concat`

```
# input:
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '4'],
                      'B': ['3', '6']})
 

df_B = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['3', '9'],
                       'B': ['4', '5'],
                       'C': ['8', '1']})
df = pd.concat([df_A, df_B]).reset_index()
df

# output:

    A   B   C
0   1   3   NaN
1   4   6   NaN
2   3   4   8
3   9   5   1
```

I guess there is a problem with your csv such as columns without header etc..